# Python script for Leibniz number row

Tags: python, pi

I am trying to write simple script in Python 2.7 for calculating Pi. I am interested in Leibniz formula:

π = (4/1) - (4/3) + (4/5) - (4/7) + (4/9) - (4/11) + (4/13) - (4/15) ...

So I consider "(4/1) - (4/3)" as X, and 1-3-5 as y, y+2, y+4....

I wrote this script:

```
def pi():
    p = 0.0
    y = 1.0
    x = 4.0/y - 4.0/(y+2.0)
    for i in range(10000):
        p = p + x
        y += 4.0
    print p

pi()
```

It isn't working as intended; could you explain why?

Comment: What precisely does *"isn't working well"* mean? Give a [mcve].

Comment: In your for loop, x always stays the same. And you add that constant to x 10,000 times. While you calculate a new y in every round, it is not used at all to calculate an approximation to pi.

Comment: Oh, thats why. Thanks =)

Comment: FWIW, the Leibniz formula is one of the slowest ways known to compute π. It's basically computing `4 * arctan(1)` using the Taylor series for arctan. You get the result much quicker using that series with [Machin-like formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machin-like_formula).

Comment: Sure thing, but I was more interested why my code wasn't working, then how to calculate PI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one works:

```
def pi():
    p = 0.0
    y = 3.0
    x = 4.0 - 4/y
    for i in range(5000):
        y += 2
        x = x + 4/y
        y += 2
        x = x - 4/y
        print x

pi()
```

Comment: But convergence is not exacly fast, is it?

Answer (score 0):

@Ukimiku's answer works if you want to use your `x` and `y` approach.

Here's an alternative approach using the actual formula:

```
def pi():
    p = 0.0
    for i in range(10000):
        p += 4 * ((-1)**i) / float(2 * i + 1)

    print p
```

For `range(10000)` this will print

```
3.14149265359
```